# Reformat Paypal Callback to Custom URL Format Using htaccess

Tags: regex, api, .htaccess, paypal

Based on my settings, Paypal returns the following sample response:

```
http://www.mydomain.com/some-seo-text-buy-callback.html?token=EC-80997676W8765&PayerID=KHDGEYEDJKD
```

I want all developers to follow the client-specified structure of the handling controllers and modules and the Paypal responses just fails to be segmented properly. So I inserted this line to the htaccess file:

```
RewriteRule ^some-seo-text-(.*)-(.*)\.html?token=(.*)-(.*)&PayerID=(.*)  /index.php?c=$1&m=$2&token=$3-$4&payerid=$5 [L]
```

Still, it fails. I'm guessing it's not falling into the rule. As you can see I'm bad with regex and I have no time to study it coz we're really on a tight schedule.

Can somebody tell me where am I doing it wrong and kindly point me out to the right direction?

Thankee sais! :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to match the query string part separately, something like this (not tested):

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} token=(\w+-\w+)&PayerID=(\w+)
RewriteRule ^some-seo-text-(\w+)-(\w+)\.html /index.php?c=$1&m=$2&token=%1&payerid=%2 [L]
```

Comment: Would this not affect other URL's not having the 'token' and 'PayerID' query strings?

Comment: The `RewriteCond` applies to the following `RewriteRule` -- both have to match before anything happens

Comment: Just a minor mod and it works. Thanks!

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} token=(\w+-\w+)&PayerID=(\w+)
RewriteRule ^group-buying-philippines-(\w+)-(\w+)\.html  /index.php?c=$1&m=$2&token=%1&payerid=%2 [L]