# Paypal with Htaccess Mod_Rewrite

Tags: php, regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, paypal

I've got a problem with Paypal and Htaccess, I can't figure it out how can I integrate the Paypal query string with my mod_rewrite directive.
I have already tried to use the suggestion of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5308652/reformat-paypal-callback-to-custom-url-format-using-htaccess) but it doesn't suits to me.

I've got this directive that take cares of all the request (views)

```
# Routes
RewriteRule ^private/([^/]*)$ /private.php?view=$1 [L]
```

So if the URL is http://www.site.com/private/foo of course the real URL is private.php?view=foo this works like a charm.

The problem is that I want to use the same directive for paypal, I mean I want to create something like this

```
http://www.site.com/private/payments?tx=1234&st=Completed&amt=5.00&cc=USD&cm=&item_number=
```

Where /private/payments is private.php?view=payments so, as you can see, I got two *?* and this is not good because all the paypal's parameters will be ignored. How can I edit the htaccess to gain all the params ? I can't find a solution :/

Thanks for any answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not "great" with mod rewrite but you can create a proxy script that is outside your normal folder structures and uses PHP to grab that variables and pass it back up to your application.

Comment: I can't use another folder due a lack of $_SESSION and cookie stuff. I really need that the payments goes in the same dir structure (mention above)